# How to Check entered Phone number is valid from Phone Directory

Tags: android

Friend's
      I'm sending an SMS from my android device,here i enter the number manually in the edittext box,and i have message to send,here how can i check the entered phone  number is valid number from phone directory.help me..

Answer (score 0):

Try [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/). Google uses it in android 4.0 and above and it looks like it can handle verification.